# What keyword "value" means?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, keyword

```
struct TreeNode
{
    int value;
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;
};
```

I'm studying some code of binary tree data structure and i stumbled upon something i never seen yet, can somebody explain what keyword `value` means? It confused me, because all the members in struct are green in my IDE.

Comment: value is just a variable here (not a keyword). An element of the structure. What do you put in a node? A value it stands for. Here, value variable represents that value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not keyword, it's just a name of struct member of type `int`.

```
TreeNode node;
node.value = 1;
std::cout << node.value << std::endl;
```

Comment: Never mind, it confused me, because all the members in struct are green in my IDE.

Comment: @DraganItmSmoljan It stores that value of the node in the tree, so that there is some metric to evaluate the nodes which can be used to arrange them in a specific way (so that that a node can be found quickly, for example).